Number of divisor of $5^{7}\times 7^{10}$ of the form $3k+2$, $k\geq 0$
Reference Question:
The number of and sum of all divisor which are odd and are of the form $3k+2$ for the number $n=2^{7}\times 3^{2}\times 5^{1}\times 7^{1}$
My approach: Since number is odd and is of the form $3k+2$ are $5$ and $35$
So I got answer as Number of divisor = $2$ and sum = $40$
My doubt about title Question:
Is there easy method to find divisor of the form $3k+2$ and $3k+1$ if number is biggger for example $5^{7}\times 7^{10}$.
Since total divisors of above question is $(7+1)(10+1)=88$ but it is difficult to list all of them and find divisor of the form $3k+2$.
$n=(3+2)^{7}\times(6+1)^{10}$
But I don't know how to proceed further?

You need to say where this question came from, please. Is it your homework?

@Mike This question was given to me by my friend....he is a teacher in grade 12th and have lectures tomorrow regarding this

This makes no sense. The title says $5^7\times 7^{10}$, the question body says $2^{7}\times 3^{2}\times 5^{1}\times 7^{1}$. (Also, you seem to have used $n$ to mean two different things, which further confuses the issue.)

Questions is about My doubt

Let $\chi_0$ and $\chi_1$ be the two Dirichlet characters modulo $3$:
$$
\chi_0(d) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } 3\nmid d,\\
0, &\text{if } 3\mid d;
\end{cases}
\qquad
\chi_1(d) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } d\equiv1\pmod3,\\
-1, &\text{if } d\equiv2\pmod3,\\
0, &\text{if } 3\mid d.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\tfrac12\bigl( \chi_0(d)-\chi_1(d) \bigr) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } d\equiv2\pmod3,\\
0, &\text{if } d\not\equiv2\pmod3,
\end{cases}
$$
and so the number of divisors of $n$ of the form $3k+2$ is exactly
$$
\sum_{d\mid n} \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } d\equiv2\pmod3,\\
0, &\text{if } d\not\equiv2\pmod3
\end{cases}
= \sum_{d\mid n} \tfrac12\bigl( \chi_0(d)-\chi_1(d) \bigr)
= \tfrac12\sum_{d\mid n} \chi_0(d) - \tfrac12\sum_{d\mid n} \chi_1(d).
$$
Both sums on the right-hand side are multiplicative functions, and so it suffices to work out their values on prime powers. It's not hard to show that when $p$ is prime and $j\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{d\mid p^j} \chi_0(d) = f_0(p^j) := \begin{cases}
j+1, &\text{if } p\ne3,\\
1, &\text{if } p=3;
\end{cases}
\qquad
\sum_{d\mid p^j} \chi_1(d) = f_1(p^j) := \begin{cases}
j+1, &\text{if } p\equiv1\pmod3,\\
0, &\text{if } p\equiv2\pmod3 \text{ and $j$ is odd},\\
1, &\text{if } p\equiv2\pmod3 \text{ and $j$ is even},\\
1, &\text{if } p=3.
\end{cases}
$$
With these definitions, the number of divisors of $n = p_1^{j_1} \cdots p_\ell^{j_\ell}$ of the form $3k+2$ is
$$
\frac12 \prod_{i=1}^\ell f_0(p_i^{j_i}) - \frac12 \prod_{i=1}^\ell f_1(p_i^{j_i}).
$$

Could you please elaborate on "Both sums on the right-hand side are multiplicative functions"? Is it a general property?

Note that we also want the divisors to be odd, so we are looking for divisors which are $5$ modulo 6. A similar analysis can be done in that case.

@user If $f$ is a multiplicative function, then so is $\sum_{d \vert n} f(d)$.

@DanielArreola Ah yes, there's a mismatch between the title and content of the post that I missed.

In your example of $5^7 \cdot 7^{10}$ note that $5 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and $7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  If you want a factor equivalent to $2 \pmod 3$ you need an odd number of factors of $5$.  The number of factors of $7$ does not matter because multiplying by $1$ doesn't change anything.  So there are $4$ choices for the number of factors of $5$ and $11$ choices for the number of factors of $7$ to get a factor of the large number that is equivalent to $2 \pmod 3$.  The sum of them is $(5^1+5^3+5^5+5^7)(\frac {7^{11}-1}{7-1})$  For factors equivalent to $1 \pmod 7$ you take all the even powers of $5$ so again there are $44$ and the sum is $\frac 15$ of the previous sum.
